# The difference between two rational numbers always is a rational number

Tags: rational-numbers

Claim: The difference between two rational numbers always is a rational number

Proof: You have a/b - c/d with a,b,c,d being integers and b,d not equal to 0.

Then:

a/b - c/d ----> ad/bd - bc/bd -----> (ad - bc)/bd

Since ad, bc, and bd are integers since integers are closed under the operation of multiplication and ad-bc is an integer since integers are closed under the operation of subtraction, then (ad-bc)/bd is a rational number since it is in the form of 1 integer divided by another and the denominator is not eqaul to 0 since b and d were not equal to 0. Thus a/b - c/d is a rational number.

Comment: Yep that's right.

Comment: I don't downvote, and I'm not sure exactly why someone did, but you technically didn't ask a question. And I'm not sure why this is prefaced with "best answer"

Answer (score 0):

Another definition
of rational number is
a real number $x$ such that
there exists a non-zero integer $n$
for which
$nx$ is an integer.

Since
$bd(a/b-c/d)
=ad-bc
$
is an integer,
$(a/b-c/d)
$
is rational.